# Trying to write function that recursively counts the number of times word appears in a text file in Python

Tags: python

Trying to write function that recursively counts the number of times word appears in a text file in Python.

```
def word_count(filename, word):
with open('C:/Users/Ibrahim/Desktop/file.txt', 'r') as f:
    result_list = [x.split(',') for x in f.readlines()]
    for i in result_list:
        if i == word:
            return word_count(filename,word)
```

is what I currently have.

Comment: Use Counter, a inbuilt module...

Comment: can you share your txt file preview?

Comment: Few things: 1. Every recursive function must have a terminating condition. You don't have one. 2. You don't seem to be keeping a count of word matches anywhere. 3. Calling `wordcount` from within `with open(...)` means, each time the function is called, you have an open file descriptor.

Comment: "hello hello hello" is my text file

Answer (score 1):

I Think it may helpful for you:

```
import sys, re


def word_count(filename, niddle, splitter=","):
    regex_pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, splitter))
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        words = [ word  for line in f.read().splitlines() for word in re.split(regex_pattern, line)]

    words = filter(None, words)
    print "Total Words :", len(words)
    print "Searching %s in list" % niddle
    print "Total Occurance : %d" % words.count(niddle)


def main(argv):
    splitter = ","

    if len(argv)==3:
        filename, word, splitter = argv
    elif len(argv)==2:
        filename, word = argv
        splitter = splitter
    else:
        print "Usage : word_count.py <file> <word> <splitter>"
        sys.exit()

    word_count(filename, word, splitter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` is your friend here, i.e.:

```
from collections import Counter
f = open('yourfile.txt', 'r')
counts = Counter(f.read().split())
print counts
```

To check if a specific word exists:

```
if "myword" in counts:
    print "exists"
```

To get a specific word count value, use:

```
print counts.get('myword')
# or simply
print counts['myword']
```

---

Note:

A `Counter` is simply a `dict` subclass and supports all the dict operators and methods.